# How to access each member of a std::string?

Tags: c++, string

How can I access each member in a std::string variable?  For example, if I have

```
string buff;
```

suppose `buff` conatains `"10 20 A"` as ASCII content.  How could I then access 10, 20, and A separately?

Comment: well "10" is not a character in its string representation, it is two characters.  Are you asking how to split a string?

Comment: Well, ⒑ is U+2491 but that's not ASCII ;)

Comment: @Eds n @Msalterd , yes i know that 10 is int but i put that int into string

Comment: I didn't say ten is an int, I said that the string "10" consists of two characters.  You ask *How can I access each member in a std::string variable*, from which I assume you are asking how to access the string character by character.  You then go on to say that "10" should be considered as a single "element", so the questions doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer for you on SO:

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

There are many ways to skin that cat...

Answer (score 3):

You can access the strings by index. i.e duff[0], duff[1] and duff[2].

I just tried. This works.

```
string helloWorld[2] = {"HELLO", "WORLD"};
char c = helloWorld[0][0];
cout << c;
```

It outputs "H"

Comment: actually i have vector of string and thats why i cant access as like str[vactor_index][0]

Comment: @bala Try using the `.at(index)` member function.

Comment: U mean an array of strings? I'm pretty sure it works. Let me try it out for myself first.

Answer (score 1):

Well I see you have tagged both C and C++.

If you are using C, strings are an array of characters. You can access each character like you would a normal array:

```
char a = duff[0];
char b = duff[1];
char c = duff[2];
```

If you are using C++ and using a character array, see above. If you are using a `std::string` (this is why C and C++ should be tagged separately), there are many ways you can access each character in the string:

```
// std::string::iterator if you want the string to be modifiable
for (std::string::const_iterator i = duff.begin(); i != duff.end(); ++i)
{
}
```

or:

`char c = duff.at(i); // where i is the index; the same as duff[i]`

and probably more.

Comment: @Marlon- I don't think this answers the OP's question.  This will hand back individual characters, rather than the integer literals made up by those characters.